# Why is my node_modules folder full of so many files I have not installed?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm creating a nodeJS application and struggling to upload it onto my server. I only have 6 dependencies yet for some reason my node_modules folder has 119 folder in it. Do I need the ones that I have not installed or have in my dependencies in my pack.json?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you install/import certain dependencies, they come along with many other packages that are also imported. If you are definite about your dependencies, you can delete the rest. But if you aren't, deleting them may just cause broken dependencies.

Comment: Also, this is opinionated question, kindly re-frame your question and refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand what type of questions we expect. Cheers :)

Comment: If you have doubts about other dependencies you can take delete or move node_module folder then make sure `package.json` has right dependencies and then run `npm install`. Now you can compare node_module with old node_module

Comment: there is no need to upload the `node_modules` folder on server; this folder will automatically generate/create (on in other sense those dependencies) when you will execute `npm install` command on server.

Comment: Don't forget that dependencies of you dependencies might be installed at the root too. You can have more details [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

- According to [Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/meta/topics/dependencies/) **Tools section**

Node.js is all about modularity, and with that comes the need for a quality package manager; for this purpose, npm was made. With npm comes the largest selection of community-created packages of any programming ecosystem, which makes building Node.js apps quick and easy

- How dependencies are managed

Each library / **dependency** you add to your project must have a semantic version as `1.2.x` and can either has other **dependencies** used in it or none.

So if each dependency you added to your project has its own dependencies with different versions this will make the package manager you are using add them to `node_modules`

Project dependencies with dependencies that are common and have no breaking API / semantic version are bubbled up to your `node_modules` directory and the rest of dependencies versions which aren't common live in their own `node_modules` directory in the libraries you added to your project

This is a general idea of how dependencies are managed and the reason for Node.js modularity.

There are also downsides to this workflow as said by **Ryan Dahl** the original developer of Node.js, because `node_modules` directory becomes bloated.

You should listen to one of his talks [10 Things I Regret About Node.js - Ryan Dahl - JSConf EU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3BM9TB-8yA)

Answer (score 0):

**The dependencies you've installed are reliant on other dependencies, just like your code is dependent on the ones you've installed.**

**That is why there are so many other folders.**

You can see a list of all the other dependencies on which the library you installed is dependent, by running:

`npm view (package name) dependencies`

For visual learners, this concept is well demonstrated [in this portion of this video](https://youtu.be/P3aKRdUyr0s?t=359).